# Is there a word for the day after a due day?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word for the succeeding day after the last day of a period?

Let’s say I had to do a homework assignment and I had to submit it before a specific date. One that due date passes, I may be subject to penalties according to the number of days late.

Here is another example. Suppose I had to pay a bill until a specific date. I'm running late by one day. I can still pay, but I have to pay interest too, according to the number of days in late.

If it was one day late, is there a word for that?

What if it were two days late? Is there a word for the second of the two, or for both these days together?

Comment: The word for all those things is either *late* or *overdue*. If you are a minute or a day or a month past a deadline, you are *late*.

Comment: I'm wondering if there's an antonym of *eve* that fits the description "day after".

Comment: The word is *morrow*, it's no longer used, and I'm not sure it was ever used in association with due dates.

Comment: @PeterShor What jape is this that would consign [the morrow](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=on+the+morrow%2Cfor+the+morrow%2Ctill+the+morrow%2Cuntil+the+morrow&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=0&smoothing=3) to [olden tomes of yesteryear](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=like+unto%2Cis+become%2Cerstwhile%2Colden&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=0&smoothing=5)?

Comment: 'tis but an old man's fancy for it doth still fall upon mine ears even on this good day.

Comment: @Jim *Tomorrow and tomorrow and tomorrow . . . and all our yesterdays . . . signifying nothing.*

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to refer to the payment directly and to the number of days indirectly allowing you to use the term:

> [*in arrears*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/arrears): the state of being behind in the discharge of obligations *< in arrears with the rent >*

You may then say things like:

> My payment is two days in arrears.

Comment: +1 Is it just me or is the singular _arrear_ rarely used nowadays? Even Chrome's spell-checker is complaining about it ...

Answer (score 1):

While not specific to days, there are a couple of terms that are related to the *period* after a deadline. They are:

- [Grace period](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/grace_period): (*idiomatic*) A length of time during which rules or penalties do not take effect or are withheld.

  *“The fees begin to accrue after a one-month grace period.”*
- [Redemption period](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tax_lien_sale#Redemption_process) (Wikipedia link is just an example):  But a redemption period usually begins once a deadline has passed (and often after a “grace period”), and [redeeming](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/redeem) the situation often involves the payment of penalties of some sort.

These terms are involved in everything from banking and taxation to domain registration.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by Robusto, the most common term would be *one day late* or *one day overdue*.  Subsequent delay would be *two days late/overdue* and so forth.

The term *past due* could also be used, as in *one day past due*. *Post due* might also be used, but I think this would be less common and a bit formal.

I do not know of a single word, other than *morrow* (and its limitations) as discussed in comments.